# WebDeploy unable to deploy package

Tags: xconnect, installation, web-deploy

Web Deploy is unable to deploy package. I have all the prerequistes installed and have double checked that the Sitecore psgallary and Sitecore gallery are trusted repos and I am not sure why I am not able to connect to local as I have tried my system password as well as all default passwords as well. I have also opened all the ports and firewall.

this is my log file from the error from web deploy

```
The property 'FullName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
The property 'FullName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
The property 'FullName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
The property 'FullName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
The property 'FullName' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.
                      ************************************
                           Sitecore Install Framework
                                 Version - 2.2.0
                      ************************************


WorkingDirectory       : C:\Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1
WhatIf                 : False
Verbose                : SilentlyContinue
Configuration          : C:\Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (Setup XP0 Developer Workstation rev. 1\XP0-SingleDeveloper.json
Debug                  : SilentlyContinue
AutoRegisterExtensions : False
WarningAction          : Continue
ErrorAction            : Stop
InformationAction      : Continue





[------------------- GeneratePasswords : SetVariable -------------------------]

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreatePaths : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[IdentityServerCertificates_CreatePaths]:[Create] C:\certificates

[ IdentityServerCertificates_Display... : WriteInformation --------------------]
Certificate Password: w:3l{8(Z7>GLSL7wF3En

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateR... : NewRootCertificate ------------------]
Exported certificate file C:\certificates\SitecoreRootCert.pfx

[ IdentityServerCertificates_CreateS... : NewSignedCertificate ----------------]
Exported certificate file C:\certificates\sc93identityserver.dev.local.pfx

[ IdentityServer_DownloadWDP [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[---------- IdentityServer_CreatePaths : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreatePaths]:[Create] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93identityserver.dev.local

[-------- IdentityServer_CreateAppPool : AppPool -----------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Exists] sc93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.identityType => ApplicationPoolIdentity
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] managedRuntimeVersion => 
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.loadUserProfile => True
[IdentityServer_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.idleTimeoutAction => Suspend

[ IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStore... : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\sc93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Path] C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\4ce92a3197594de8579f7c9ecf5abfaa_02aa24db-a81e-4084-8fe2-9bca9ea91e91
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Rights] Read
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Inherit] None
[IdentityServer_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Propagate] None

[-------- IdentityServer_CreateWebsite : Website -----------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreateWebsite]:[Exists] sc93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_CreateWebsite]:[Setting] applicationPool => sc93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_CreateWebsite]:[Setting] physicalPath => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93identityserver.dev.local

[---------- IdentityServer_StopWebsite : ManageWebsite -----------------------]
[IdentityServer_StopWebsite]:[Stop] sc93identityserver.dev.local
Website sc93identityserver.dev.local is already Stopped

[---------- IdentityServer_StopAppPool : ManageAppPool -----------------------]
[IdentityServer_StopAppPool]:[Stop] sc93identityserver.dev.local

[ IdentityServer_CreateRegistryStora... : ManageKeyStorage --------------------]
sc93identityserver.dev.local
Pool user name: 'IIS APPPOOL\sc93identityserver.dev.local'
Pool SID: 'S-1-5-82-55518118-3768486615-2780394426-1638643333-4031482231'
Use existed key storage: S-1-5-82-55518118-3768486615-2780394426-1638643333-4031482231
Use existed key storage: S-1-5-82-55518118-3768486615-2780394426-1638643333-4031482231

[- IdentityServer_RemoveDefaultBinding : WebBinding --------------------------]
[IdentityServer_RemoveDefaultBinding]:[Remove] 
protocol bindingInformation sslFlags
-------- ------------------ --------
http     *:80:                     0




[ IdentityServer_CreateBindingsWithT... : WebBinding --------------------------]
Web Binding already exists for sc93identityserver.dev.local

Name                           Value                                                                                    
----                           -----                                                                                    
HostHeader                     sc93identityserver.dev.local                                                             
Protocol                       https                                                                                    




[----- IdentityServer_CreateHostHeader : HostHeader --------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreateHostHeader]:[Backup] Created - C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.backup
[IdentityServer_CreateHostHeader]:[Exists] 127.0.0.1 => sc93identityserver.dev.local

[------- IdentityServer_SetPermissions : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\sc93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93identityserver.dev.local
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Rights] FullControl
System.Object[]
[IdentityServer_SetPermissions]:[Propagate] None

[----------- IdentityServer_InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe

[-- IdentityServer_CreateLicenseFolder : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[IdentityServer_CreateLicenseFolder]:[Create] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93identityserver.dev.local\sitecoreruntime

[----------- IdentityServer_SetLicense : Copy --------------------------------]
[IdentityServer_SetLicense]:[Copying] C:\ResourceFiles\license.xml => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93identityserver.dev.local\sitecoreruntime

[ IdentityServer_CustomConfigFile [S... : Copy --------------------------------]

[--------- IdentityServer_StartAppPool : ManageAppPool -----------------------]
[IdentityServer_StartAppPool]:[Start] sc93identityserver.dev.local

[--------- IdentityServer_StartWebsite : ManageWebsite -----------------------]
[IdentityServer_StartWebsite]:[Start] sc93identityserver.dev.local

[---- XConnectCertificates_CreatePaths : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[XConnectCertificates_CreatePaths]:[Create] C:\certificates

[ XConnectCertificates_DisplayPassword : WriteInformation --------------------]
Certificate Password: oS.2%1tg@{i1@Va^@rM(

[- XConnectCertificates_CreateRootCert : NewRootCertificate ------------------]
Exported certificate file C:\certificates\SitecoreRootCert.pfx

[ XConnectCertificates_CreateSignedCert : NewSignedCertificate ----------------]
Exported certificate file C:\certificates\sc93xconnect.dev.local.pfx

[-------- XConnectSolr_UnloadCores [1] : ManageSolrCore ----------------------]
[XConnectSolr_UnloadCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://localhost:8983/solr
[XConnectSolr_UnloadCores [1]]:[SolrCore] Performing Unload on https://localhost:8983/solr


[-------- XConnectSolr_UnloadCores [2] : ManageSolrCore ----------------------]
[XConnectSolr_UnloadCores [2]]:[Requesting] https://localhost:8983/solr
[XConnectSolr_UnloadCores [2]]:[SolrCore] Performing Unload on https://localhost:8983/solr


[------------- XConnectSolr_CleanCores : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Clean] C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\sc93_xdb
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Clean] C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\sc93_xdb_rebuild
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Create] C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\sc93_xdb
[XConnectSolr_CleanCores]:[Create] C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\sc93_xdb_rebuild

[------- XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [1] : Copy --------------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [1]]:[Copying] C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\configsets\_default\* => C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\sc93_xdb

[------- XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [2] : Copy --------------------------------]
[XConnectSolr_PrepareCores [2]]:[Copying] C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\configsets\_default\* => C:\Solr\solr811solr-8.1.1\server\solr\sc93_xdb_rebuild

[-------- XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1] : ManageSolrCore ----------------------]
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[Requesting] https://localhost:8983/solr
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [1]]:[SolrCore] Performing Create on https://localhost:8983/solr


[-------- XConnectSolr_CreateCores [2] : ManageSolrCore ----------------------]
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [2]]:[Requesting] https://localhost:8983/solr
[XConnectSolr_CreateCores [2]]:[SolrCore] Performing Create on https://localhost:8983/solr


[--- XConnectXP0_DownloadWDP [Skipped] : DownloadFile ------------------------]

[------------- XConnectXP0_CreatePaths : EnsurePath --------------------------]
[XConnectXP0_CreatePaths]:[Create] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93xconnect.dev.local

[----------- XConnectXP0_CreateAppPool : AppPool -----------------------------]
[XConnectXP0_CreateAppPool]:[Exists] sc93xconnect.dev.local
[XConnectXP0_CreateAppPool]:[Setting] processModel.identityType => ApplicationPoolIdentity

[ XConnectXP0_SetAppPoolCertStorePer... : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[XConnectXP0_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\sc93xconnect.dev.local
[XConnectXP0_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Path] C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\d462a7fc7bc7201eaea8bfa88cb1a941_02aa24db-a81e-4084-8fe2-9bca9ea91e91
[XConnectXP0_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Rights] Read
[XConnectXP0_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Inherit] None
[XConnectXP0_SetAppPoolCertStorePermissions]:[Propagate] None

[----------- XConnectXP0_CreateWebsite : Website -----------------------------]
[XConnectXP0_CreateWebsite]:[Exists] sc93xconnect.dev.local
[XConnectXP0_CreateWebsite]:[Setting] applicationPool => sc93xconnect.dev.local
[XConnectXP0_CreateWebsite]:[Setting] physicalPath => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93xconnect.dev.local

[------------- XConnectXP0_StopWebsite : ManageWebsite -----------------------]
[XConnectXP0_StopWebsite]:[Stop] sc93xconnect.dev.local
Website sc93xconnect.dev.local is already Stopped

[------------- XConnectXP0_StopAppPool : ManageAppPool -----------------------]
[XConnectXP0_StopAppPool]:[Stop] sc93xconnect.dev.local
App Pool 'sc93xconnect.dev.local' is Stopped

[-------- XConnectXP0_StopServices [1] : ManageService -----------------------]
[XConnectXP0_StopServices [1]]:[Updating] sc93xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker
Service 'sc93xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker' does not exist

[-------- XConnectXP0_StopServices [2] : ManageService -----------------------]
[XConnectXP0_StopServices [2]]:[Updating] sc93xconnect.dev.local-MarketingAutomationService
Service 'sc93xconnect.dev.local-MarketingAutomationService' does not exist

[-------- XConnectXP0_StopServices [3] : ManageService -----------------------]
[XConnectXP0_StopServices [3]]:[Updating] sc93xconnect.dev.local-ProcessingEngineService
Service 'sc93xconnect.dev.local-ProcessingEngineService' does not exist

[------ XConnectXP0_RemoveServices [1] : RemoveService -----------------------]
Could not find service: 'sc93xconnect.dev.local-IndexWorker'

[------ XConnectXP0_RemoveServices [2] : RemoveService -----------------------]
Could not find service: 'sc93xconnect.dev.local-MarketingAutomationService'

[------ XConnectXP0_RemoveServices [3] : RemoveService -----------------------]
Could not find service: 'sc93xconnect.dev.local-ProcessingEngineService'

[---- XConnectXP0_RemoveDefaultBinding : WebBinding --------------------------]
[XConnectXP0_RemoveDefaultBinding]:[Remove] 
protocol bindingInformation sslFlags
-------- ------------------ --------
http     *:80:                     0




[ XConnectXP0_CreateBindingsWithThum... : WebBinding --------------------------]

[ XConnectXP0_SetClientCertificatePe... : WebsiteClientCert -------------------]
[XConnectXP0_SetClientCertificatePermissions]:[sc93xconnect.dev.local] [Setting] sslFlags => SslNegotiateCert

[ XConnectXP0_SupportListManagerLarg... : IISConfiguration --------------------]
[XConnectXP0_SupportListManagerLargeUpload]:[sc93xconnect.dev.local] [Setting] uploadReadAheadSize => 491520000

[-------- XConnectXP0_CreateHostHeader : HostHeader --------------------------]
[XConnectXP0_CreateHostHeader]:[Backup] Created - C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.backup
[XConnectXP0_CreateHostHeader]:[Exists] 127.0.0.1 => sc93xconnect.dev.local

[---------- XConnectXP0_SetPermissions : FilePermissions ---------------------]
[XConnectXP0_SetPermissions]:[Allow] IIS AppPool\sc93xconnect.dev.local
[XConnectXP0_SetPermissions]:[Path] C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc93xconnect.dev.local
[XConnectXP0_SetPermissions]:[Rights] FullControl
System.Object[]
[XConnectXP0_SetPermissions]:[Propagate] None

[-------------- XConnectXP0_InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD
More Information: Could not deploy package.
Unable to connect to target server '(local)'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
A network-related or instance-specifi
c error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
The system cannot find the file specified
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.

Error: Could not deploy package.

Error: Unable to connect to target server '(local)'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.

Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connectio
ns. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Error: The system cannot find the file specified

Error count: 1.

Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
[TIME] 00:04:10
Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
```

Comment: Can you verify you have turned on SQL authentication. Windows authentication comes out of the box with express. But you need to turn SQL logins on.

Comment: What version of SQL are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exactly the same issue.

There are two ways to resolve this.

**Approach 1:**

Remove your SQL server complete and install it again step by step add current user while installing it.(I used SQL server 2016 to avoid the issues)

And then try to install Sitecore.

**Approach 2:**

In current condition you can use below steps to mitigate the issue

**Set the path to the Data-Tier application framework in Windows Registry:**

1. Install the Data-Tier Application Framework via Web Platform Installer
2. Locate the installation folder of the MS SQL server version that you are using:

   `\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>`
3. Find the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll file in one of the subfolders:

   `\DAC\bin or \SDK\Assemblies`
4. Store the full path to this subfolder as a DacFxPath value (String type) under the registry key

   `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3`

**Set the path to the SQL ScriptDOM and CLRTypes components in Windows Registry:**

1. Locate the installation folder of the MS SQL server version that you are using:

   `\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\<version>`
2. Find the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom.dll and Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll files in one of the subfolders:

   `\DAC\bin or \SDK\Assemblies`
3. Store the full path to this subfolder as a DacFxDependenciesPath value (String type) under the registry key

   `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3`

After this run your installation back. There is another blog ([click me](https://www.sitecorespark.com/blog/2017/11/sitecore-installation-framework-error-processing-pools)) where you will find few steps to check on your machine.

I used **Approach 1** and it resolved my issues 100%. Hope this will help you.